# Is BootPicker Snow Leopard compatible?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, multi-boot, boot-camp

I have Windows 7 installed using bootcamp and I'd like to see a menu (for about 5 secs) on system startup to choose which OS to run.

BootPicker is exactly what I want, but no screen appears on startup, I wonder if its SL compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googled it and found that its incompatible since 10.5.2, ah, it was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Just hold down the option key and it'll let you choose.